# permission denied when opening any notebook in jupyter notebook browser

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, virtual-machine, ubuntu-18.04, permission-denied

When I am trying to open a notebook in the browser through jupyter notebook then I am getting an error message that the permission is denied. I am able to create new notebooks but could not open any other downloaded notebooks. I even tried this command `sudo jupyter-notebook --allow-root` but its displaying a message that 'sudo: jupyter-notebook command not found'. I am opening jupyter notebook from virtual environment through Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I am a beginner in jupyter notebook so please help me out. I would be highly grateful.

The path to my home directory is `C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\snesh

This is my home directory.
[Image of Home Directory on Jupyter Notebook browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fnj6.png)

And when I am trying to open any of the notebooks then I am getting this error message displayed.
[Image of error message displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hc0WS.png)

Comment: you have installed ubuntu(as a virtual machine) inside windows? using hyper v or virtual box?

Comment: yes I have installed ubuntu(as a virtual machine) inside windows through WSL(Windows Subsystem for Linux). I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS distro for WSL from the microsoft store.

Comment: I understand you do not have access  to an external notebook, but can you open the notebook somewhere else ? If it is the case you may copy its content in a new notebook you have access to.

Comment: when I opened jupyter notebook through command prompt which is from a different home directory where I again copied and pasted external notebooks then I am able to get access to it and it opened. Thanks!  But, when I am opening the jupyter notebook from virtual environment then I am not getting access to it. I want to open the external notebooks through virtual environment too because I have installed some packages there itself. How can this be resolved? @CatalinaChircu

Comment: You cannot have access from the virtual environement to an external file. Open a notebook in your venv and then paste in it the content of the other file. I do not see another way to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you but I want to load a csv file into my notebook and do some stuffs which require turicreate package(which is installed in virtual environment). When I am trying to load that csv file into my notebook then again I am getting a message that permission is denied. What should I do? @CatalinaChircu

Comment: Did you create your csv file in your venv ?

Comment: No, actually I downloaded it and pasted it in that directory and its not giving me permission to open that file. @CatalinaChircu

Comment: Then try to create a csv file with the same content within the virtual environement. You will be able to access a file created while you are in your venv. Copy/ paste for example as I wrote before.

Comment: Now do you really need a venv when working  in a notebook? Try working without using venv.